# How to detect which JavaScript function used at URI for encoding and how to encode not encoded URI parts?

Tags: javascript, urlencode, urldecode

I have some URLs that are encoded by encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent(). Some **parts** of it may not be encoded too. You can see some examples:

```
www.yazlm.com/üı

www.yazlm.com/ı%C4%C1%FD

http://www.yazlm.com/abc%def%E2%80%99

www.yazlm.com/привет

http://www.abcyazlm.com/i?i=http%3A%2F%2Fwww
```

How can I write a function to compare two URLs are either same or not. For example consider that four URLs:

- First one's path is encoded by encodeURI()
- Second one's path is
  encoded by encodeURIComponent()
- Third one is not encoded
- Fourth one's path's some parts are encoded and some parts are not. (`www.url.com/encoded/plain`)

I want to detect that they are all same.

Comment: *All* URLs are encoded, believe me. `www.yazlm.com/üı` is not a valid URL.

Comment: @deceze you can copy and paste this: www.seslisozluk.net/search/üı at your browser and understand that it is a valid URL. Assume that a crawler get it as www.seslisozluk.net/search/üı from this webpage and another as http://www.seslisozluk.net/search/%C3%BC%C4%B1 from another webpage. They are same but has written different.

Comment: Your browser helpfully encodes the URL behind the scenes for you. The actual URL is http://www.seslisozluk.net/search/%C3%BC%C4%B1. You can check your browser's network inspector. In fact, click on this URL and see how it's displayed as http://www.seslisozluk.net/search/üı in the address bar.

Comment: You can check my comment and understand that they are same and why this question may be asked for.